# Energy of resultant photons from meson decay

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, radiation, pions

I am a little unsure how to answer the following question, Find the energies of two photons emitted in opposite directions along the pion's original line of motion if the pion has a r.m.e of 500MEV and is moving with a Kinetic energy of 0.8 Gev.

I was planing to use the equation $$ 4E1E2 = (mc^2)^2$$  where $m$ is the rest mass of the pion.  My issue is, how do I account for the kinetic energy of the pion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is conserve energy and momentum in the lab frame.

Firstly you conserve energy in lab frame:

\begin{equation}
E_{\gamma 1} + E_{\gamma2} = E_{\pi} = 1.3GeV
\end{equation}

Then you work out what the pion's momentum was (still in the lab frame) using the mass-energy-momentum relation where the $E_\pi$ is the total kinetic and mass energy:

\begin{equation}
E_{\pi}^2 = m_{\pi}^2c^4 + p_{\pi}^2c^2
\end{equation}

Then you apply the relation connecting the photon energy and momentum:
\begin{equation}
p_{\gamma} = \frac{E_{\gamma}}{c}
\end{equation}

And conserve momentum (still in the lab frame):
\begin{equation}
\vec{p}_{\gamma1} + \vec{p}_{\gamma2} = \vec{p}_\pi
\end{equation}

Note that $\vec{p}_{\gamma1}$ and $\vec{p}_{\gamma2}$ are going to be in *opposite* directions and one of them will be in the same direction as $\vec{p}_\pi$ so you can relate the moduli of the vectors like so (if you choose $\gamma_1$ to be the one going "forward":

\begin{equation}
p_{\gamma1} - p_{\gamma2} = p_\pi
\end{equation}

Between these four equations you can solve for $E_{\gamma1}$ and $E_{\gamma2}$.

Comment: Okay, I can follow the first two equations but how do I apply the next two to solve for the energies?

Comment: @user2352274 sorry I didn't reply earlier I was busy. Good on you for figuring it out.